# Windows 10 Home Has my Sql Server (SSMS) been hacked? Weird passwords I did not assign in sys.syslogins

Tags: security, sql-server

I am running Sql Server Dev 2017 with SSMS and Windows Authentication in Windows 10 Home Edition.
My SqlServer is and always has been offline (TCP/IP is disabled for my SqlServer, no inbound rules in my firewall), and has always lived in my PC, i.e., not in any server in a network.I have 3 instances in my Server, none allows Sql Server authentication

[image]

While doing some other work, I used the table 'sys.syslogins', with this output :

[image]

I'm curious:

1. Why is there a table containing logins given I use Windows, which does not require them, given I use Win authentication?
2. Given I don't know Chinese,and the table has never been online,  how were the Chinese characters in the included pic entered?
   Can I reasonably infer someone gained physical access to my pc?
3. Where/how can I check when the login was set up? My Sql Server logs, I guess, but , where, more specifically? Maybe in my Win10 Event viewer?

Comment: Those characters are not actually "Chinese", SSMS simply does not understand, how to display the characters correctly.  To put it simply, your select statement isn't complete, by the way the password field is actually a one-way hash.  [The hash by the way is likely your own password.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081651/how-to-decode-password-from-sys-syslogins-table).  **You have not been hacked.**

Comment: @Ramhound : If I may, a question on moving a Sql Server database, several instances, between PCs, say: source and target. You detach a database from the Source and attach at the destination. not too hard, except I need to provide a path for the target to do the restoring. But how do I provide a path to a different PC? (not to a different instance on the same PC, but for an instance on a different PC.) Do I need RDP, or something like Team Viewer, or SFTP? If it's too long, I ca ask it as stand alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question1**

> Why is there a table containing logins given I use Windows, which does not require them, given I use Win authentication?

Even Windows logins require a password although you don't enter them when the connection window appears. When you enter the username (windows login), SQL server checks the password directly with Windows as stated [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/choose-an-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-ver16#:%7E:text=When%20a%20user,provided%20by%20Windows.) because it trusts it:

> When a user connects through a Windows user account, SQL Server validates the account name and password using the Windows principal token in the operating system. This means that the user identity is confirmed by Windows. SQL Server does not ask for the password, and does not perform the identity validation. Windows Authentication is the default authentication mode, and is much more secure than SQL Server Authentication. Windows Authentication uses Kerberos security protocol, provides password policy enforcement with regard to complexity validation for strong passwords, provides support for account lockout, and supports password expiration. A connection made using Windows Authentication is sometimes called a trusted connection, because SQL Server trusts the credentials provided by Windows.

**Question 2**

> Given I don't know Chinese,and the table has never been online, how were the Chinese characters in the included pic entered? Can I reasonably infer someone gained physical access to my pc?

As already stated by @Ranhound in the comments, the Chinese characters are not actually Chinese characters. As mentioned in [Character data is represented incorrectly when the code page of the client computer differs from the code page of the database in SQL Server 2005](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/character-data-is-represented-incorrectly-when-the-code-page-of-the-client-computer-differs-from-the-code-page-of-the-database-in-sql-server-2005-4ec4ad9a-319d-2592-96b5-51b6b6abdead) (also valid more recent versions), the characters not displaying correctly might be due to :

> X is stored in a non-Unicode column of code page
> Y. Additionally, the character data is not translated correctly. We do not support storing the character data of code page
> X in a column of code page
> Y.
>
> In SQL Server 2005, when you use a string literal of a non-Unicode data type, the string literal is converted by using the database's default code page that is derived from the database's collation. Storing the character data of code page X in a column of code page Y may cause data loss or data corruption.

**Question 3**

> Where/how can I check when the login was set up? My Sql Server logs, I guess, but , where, more specifically? Maybe in my Win10 Event viewer?

You can run the following query as shown [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2026/tables-and-views-for-auditing-sql-server-logins/):

```sql
SELECT [name], createdate, updatedate  , isntuser, isntgroup FROM syslogins;
```

The query will output:

> - The name of the login
> - When the login was created
> - When the login was last modified (either the password was changed or one of the settings on the login was)
> - Whether or not the login is a Windows-based user account
> - Whether or not the login is a Windows-based security group

Comment: If I may, a question on moving a Sql Server database, several instances, between PCs, say: source and target. You detach a database from the Source and attach at the destination. not too hard, except I need to provide a path for the target to do the restoring. But how do I provide a path to a different PC? (not to a different instance on the same PC, but for an instance on a different PC.) Do I need RDP, or something like Team Viewer, or SFTP? If it's too long, I ca ask it as stand alone.

Comment: @MSIS See https://sqlsolutionsgroup.com/migrate-sql-server